# Java script function suddenly stopped working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome

I am developing an application with ASP.net and VB.net. In that application i have written this simple javascript function in the popup window in order to refresh the parent window when the popup is closed.

```
 function RefreshParent() {
         if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
             window.opener.location.reload();
              }
         }
   window.onbeforeunload = RefreshParent;
```

This was working fine. But suddenly it stopped working. Its still working on Firefox and internet explorer.

**its not just a problem in my PC. I am getting this problem from every user who is using chrome to access the application.**

The function was working fine. Its just stopped working suddenly. And I can assure that  there was no such changes been made which might cause this happen. Its still working on Firefox and IE

**But i Have tried the following to see if the problem is related with chrome settings**

to see if the javascript is enable or not I double checked the content settings section in advance setting of the browser. Allow all site to run Javascript option is selected.

And I have also re installed chrome.

According to the suggestion of Jeremy I have added two alerts in the javascript function to see if the function is accessed or not.

```
     function RefreshParent() {
         alert("Accessed the function!");
         if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
             window.opener.location.reload();
              }
      }
      alert("refreshed parent window!");
      window.onbeforeunload = RefreshParent;
```

I can only see the 2nd alert. But this alert comes when i click to open the popup.

Also when I add this two alert the refreshing function also stops working in firefox (I did not checked in ie with the alert on.)

How to solve the problem

Comment: check you chrome browser `Allow popup ` it seems this might be block on your machine

Comment: The Popup window still opens. And its not just a problem in my PC. I am getting this problem from every user who is using chrome to access the application

Comment: I'm using window.location.reload on my php webapp and that seems to still work in chrome, have you tested if your function is being accessed by putting up an alert? Try putting an alert in your function and then an alert right before your window.reload and see till where it gets

Comment: I have not. How to do that? Forgive my ignorance I am novice programmer.

Comment: alert('i accessed the function'); right above your if statement
alert('I am going to redirect'); right above the window...reload();

Comment: also if it's the reload that doesn't work I also use window.location.href = 'urlhere'; to redirect to other pages (though this doesn't seem to always work in IE)

Comment: create your Js Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eetvyo3z/5/

Comment: @Satindersingh How would you create a redirect like this in jsfiddle?

Comment: I can only see the 2nd alert. But this alert comes when i click to open the popup. Also when I add this two alert the refreshing function also stops working in firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution works for me. In POPUP.vb.aspx  POPUP page I added the following line of code under button click

```
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "refresh", "var url = window.opener.location.href; window.opener.location.href = url;", True)
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "CloseWindowScript", "window.close();", True)
```

I still have the javascript function ( mentioned in the question) in the asp.net page. Its not clear why its  suddenly just stopped working in  Chrome.